# Stripe transfer amount to multiple bank accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have a ruby on rails web app where I have some users and clients.

I want to get amount from user via stripe and transfer some amount to my relevant client's bank account.

How can I do that.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Besides the fact that you have a Rails app, I can't see how this question is connected to Rails. It seems to me your question is about how Stripe works.

Comment: actually i am using php and was following https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers. But this is not working. It has been said deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Stripe Connect ( https://stripe.com/connect ) would allow you to do a multi-level marketshare.

It wouldn't allow you to directly transfer money into a client's bank account but it does allow you to pay your user directly which will then enable them to transfer it to their bank account themselves.

Finally, I believe this is also more secure than trying to safely store bank account information on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the transfer in two way the old way [from doc](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/sending-transfers) is in two steps:-

Step 1:- Collecting recipient details(You will get code on the link Ruby or PHP)

Step 2:- Creating transfers

The second way you can do this through [Managed Account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/migrating).

If you are using PHP then follow [github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) it's too easy.